# in what scope are docker-compose commands run

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am hitting issues running a start script (eg `npm run gulp-dist`) for my container as specified in my docker compose file. I traced the issue down to a node version compatibility issue which has led me to some confusion.

If I enter the container with `docker-compose run workspace bash` and then run `node -v` I get back `v10.5.0` as expected (and what my script requires).
Yet if in docker-compose I set `command: node -v` it prints `v4.2.6` when bringing up the container with `docker-compose up workspace`.

So I'm wondering *where* are the commands run that I specify in docker-compose (I thought they were run in the container once it had started). And how do I run a command in the container - I want to specify it in docker-compose as I run a different command in two different docker-compose files (one for dev env, one for production).

Note: My dev machine has node version 11, so I have no idea where four is.

Also, if run `docker-compose run workspace bash` and then run the original script, it works fine - it is just failing when run as a docker-compose command.

Here's my dockerfile (sorry, it's big):

```
# FROM laradock/workspace:1.8-71
# copied the contents of the above laradock workspace 
# dockerfile and replaced put here directly.

FROM phusion/baseimage:latest

MAINTAINER Mahmoud Zalt <mahmoud@zalt.me>

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8

ENV LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
ENV LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG=en_US.UTF-8
ENV TERM xterm

# Add the "PHP 7" ppa
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common && \
        add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php

#
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Software's Installation
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#

# Install "PHP Extentions", "libraries", "Software's"
RUN apt-get update && \
        apt-get install -y --allow-downgrades --allow-remove-essential \
        --allow-change-held-packages \
        php7.1-cli \
        php7.1-common \
        php7.1-curl \
        php7.1-intl \
        php7.1-json \
        php7.1-xml \
        php7.1-mbstring \
        php7.1-mcrypt \
        php7.1-mysql \
        php7.1-pgsql \
        php7.1-sqlite \
        php7.1-sqlite3 \
        php7.1-zip \
        php7.1-bcmath \
        php7.1-memcached \
        php7.1-gd \
        php7.1-dev \
        pkg-config \
        libcurl4-openssl-dev \
        libedit-dev \
        libssl-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        xz-utils \
        libsqlite3-dev \
        sqlite3 \
        git \
        curl \
        vim \
        nano \
        postgresql-client \
        && apt-get clean

#####################################
# Composer:
#####################################

# Install composer and add its bin to the PATH.
RUN curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php && \
        echo "export PATH=${PATH}:/var/www/vendor/bin" >> ~/.bashrc && \
        mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

# Source the bash
RUN . ~/.bashrc

#
# other - workspace specific config
#

RUN apt-get -y update && \
        apt-get install pkg-config libmagickwand-dev -y && \
        pecl install imagick

#####################################
# Non-Root User:
#####################################

# Add a non-root user to prevent files being created with root permissions on host machine.

ENV PUID 1000
ENV PGID 1000

RUN groupadd -g ${PGID} laradock && \
        useradd -u ${PUID} -g laradock -m laradock && \
        apt-get update -yqq

#####################################
# Set Timezone
#####################################

ARG TZ=UTC
ENV TZ ${TZ}
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

#####################################
# Composer:
#####################################

# Add the composer.json
COPY ./composer.json /home/laradock/.composer/composer.json

# Make sure that ~/.composer belongs to laradock
RUN chown -R laradock:laradock /home/laradock/.composer
USER laradock

# Check if global install need to be ran
ARG COMPOSER_GLOBAL_INSTALL=false
ENV COMPOSER_GLOBAL_INSTALL ${COMPOSER_GLOBAL_INSTALL}
RUN if [ ${COMPOSER_GLOBAL_INSTALL} = true ]; then \
        # run the install
        composer global install \
        ;fi

USER root

#####################################
# Node / NVM:
#####################################

# Check if NVM needs to be installed
ARG NODE_VERSION=10.5.0
ENV NODE_VERSION 10.5.0
ENV NVM_DIR /home/laradock/.nvm
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.1/install.sh | bash && \
        . $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh && \
        nvm install ${NODE_VERSION} && \
        nvm use ${NODE_VERSION} && \
        npm install -g gulp bower vue-cli \
        ;fi

# link node and nodejs
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node


# Wouldn't execute when added to the RUN statement in the above block
# Source NVM when loading bash since ~/.profile isn't loaded on non-login shell
RUN echo "" >> ~/.bashrc && \
        echo 'export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"' >> ~/.bashrc && \
        echo '[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm' >> ~/.bashrc \
        ;fi

# install required things
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install apt-transport-https && \
        curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - && \
        echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list && \
        apt-get update && apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated yarn mysql-client

# Add NVM binaries to root's .bashrc
USER root

RUN apt-get install npm -y

# set npm registry address
RUN npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/


#
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Final Touch
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#

# Clean up
USER root
RUN apt-get clean && \
        rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# Set default work directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# # copy in our code, so as not to rely on a volume in prod
COPY . /var/www

# ensure directories we need are writable
RUN chmod -R o+w /var/www/user-api-laravel/storage
RUN chmod -R o+w /var/www/user-api-laravel/bootstrap/cache
RUN chmod -R o+w /var/www/auto/storage
RUN chmod -R o+w /var/www/auto/bootstrap/cache

# install php project dependencies

RUN cd /var/www/user-api-laravel && composer install
RUN cd /var/www/auto && composer install

WORKDIR /var/www

USER root

# install auto-scalar deps
RUN cd /var/www/auto-scaler && npm i

# php.ini for cli
ADD ./php-cli.ini /etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini
```

And relevant part of docker-compose:

```
workspace:
    build:
      context: ./www-workspace
      args:
        - TZ=${WORKSPACE_TIMEZONE}
        - NODE_VERSION=${WORKSPACE_NODE_VERSION}
    command: [bash, -c, "cd /var/www/spa && npm run dist-prod"]
```

Comment: Can't tell much without the dockerfile (and the entrypoint if the image uses one). It all comes from inside the container though.

Comment: @emix Ok I added it, hope it helps.

Comment: Oh boy what a mess ;) I don't have time to analyze this. The command location may vary depending upon the shell used. The entrypoint uses some other shell (modified environment) than your `bash` when you enter the container. Thus different npm locations used, both however come from the container.

Comment: Haha, yes, it has a lot going on.... sorry for the cognitive overload. You can see not far in I use NVM to install node 10.5.0

Comment: Images should be small, focused, well formed, easy to maintain, not fit-all-in-one. Your's a hell, you will have problems such as this a lot with this one. Good luck man. You ought to read how the [`command`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#cmd-default-command-or-options) works too, especially with/without the entrypoint.

Comment: Apart from running this command on startup it works fine, I don't want to have tonnes of separate images.

Comment: In addition to breaking this up, you should probably remove all mentions of `.bashrc` in here; it doesn’t get reliably read (from your original question, `docker-compose run workspace node -v` does not start bash at all, for example).  Don’t bother with a version manager like NVM; just create an image with _only_ the single version of Node you need and your application code in it.

Comment: Hi David, thanks, running `docker-compose run workspace bash -c "node -v"` gives the same result - I just mistyped the question. Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you just use regular node install?  One of the benefit of `nvm` is the ability to have multiple version of `node` which is not what you want.  It's a simple command `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo bash -`

Comment: Thanks @Noogen I will change to that shortly, but for now when I bash in the correct version is there: 10.5.0, the problem is that when/where the docker-compose command is run, that version is not used. Any idea on what context the command is run, and why it works when I bash in to the container, but not set it as a command in docker-compose?

Comment: @Noogen also, that command to install node doesn't work (I replaced x with 5)

Comment: Create a github repo of the docker file and example how it's not working so we can try to fix it; otherwise, even simple typo is difficult to troubleshoot or demonstrate how to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still don't know what context the commands run in, but made mine work. It was due to node being installed via NVM. Or at least when I installed, as @Noogen suggested, via `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo bash -` I could then run commands against my container and they would have access to the correct node version. I had to settled for a lower node version (not 10.5.0 as I could specify with NVM) but in the end it worked so no worries.